# How to show that the sum of a function is strictly increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, monotone-functions

I have that $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$ is an enumeration of $Q$ and let 
$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n^2}&\text{if}\, x > r_n\\
0 &\text{if}\, x \le r_n
\end{cases}
\quad$
and $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x).$

I think that the function is increasing but not strictly increasing but the clearly it is strictly increasing and I dont know why it is strictly increasing. How can I see that this is indeed strictly increasing? 
 
I need to show that $f$ is discontinuous for $x \in Q$ and here is how I have reasoned : 
I know that if we take $x < r_n$, we can choose a small enough $\delta$ s.t. $f_n(y)=0$ for $y \in V_\delta(x)$. Similar reasoning applied to $x >r_n$. We can then show $f(x)$ converges unifromly by the Weierstrass N-test since 
$M_n=\frac{1}{2^n} \ge f_n(x)$ and therefore, since all $f_n$ are continuous, and $f$ converges uniformly, we conclude that $f$ is continuous. Now I dont know how to show discontinuity for $x \in Q$.

Comment: Given $a<b$ there are infinitely many rationals between $a$ and $b$, so $f(a)<f(b)$. (Is the first $f(x)$ in your display supposed to be $f_n(x)$?)

Comment: And if $x=r_n$ is rational, and $y<x$, then $f(x)-f(y)\ge n^{-2}$, so $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Comment: yes it should. Thank you

Comment: what if $a < b \le r_n$?In that case I would get $f_n(a)=f_n(b)=0$which is not strictly increasing. In what way does the fact that there are infinitely many rationals between $a$ and $b$ help me here?

Comment: You take one of those rationals between $a$ and $b$, and you call that one $r_n$, then $f(b)\ge f(a)+n^{-2}$.

Comment: Understood, david?

Comment: yes. thank you sir

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to write it up, and to post it as an answer.